# Best option to Cascade Delete in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best way to configure Cascade Delete in Entity Framework for the relashionship between Ads and Pictures. I want to delete all related pictures when I delete an Ad automatically.

Models:

```
public class Picture
{
    // Primary properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}

public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

Op1.

I found the option of adding a Foreign Key DataAnnotation Property in the Picture Entity:

```
[ForeignKey("Ad")]
public int Ad_Id { get; set; }
public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
```

This option deletes the related Pictures even without the Cascade Delete SQL-Server option set to true.

Op2.

Using FluentApi in the OnModelCreating Method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     {....}
     .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

Op3.

Controlling this at the SQL-Server level with the Cascade Delete option. This one I was not able to test with an example in EF because I don't know how to ser the Model.

I'm very confusing with all this options, is there a standard option in EF for Cascade Delete?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the default EF behaviour http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete

You already found the API option to override it.
If you have "Complex" relationships you may be FORCED to set cascade on delete to false.
But your situation seems simple enough.

The API cascade on delete just "overrides" the standard relationship pattern whether it was declared using attributes or via the API.

OP3 should work as well. You need to generate the SQL to alter the table constraints.

Just use the API to set the cascade delete option as required.
BUT be prepared for disappointment. You cant use cascade on delete in all scenarios.

See the SO posts on deleting records using EF when you only have the KEy.
You can delete an entry by placing an entity in Context with only the key set and setting the state to deleted. Perhaps a custom DeleteWhere routine...

```
  public int DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>> predicate) {
        var delList = GetList(predicate);
        foreach (var poco in delList) {
            Context.Entry(poco).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                      }
        return delList.Count;
        // or Context.SaveChanges... depending on your LUW strategy
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks. By what I saw in the EF default behaviour is that my Op1 is by default the way to go, I can even remove the property [ForeignKey("Ad")] correct? But in my case, Picture Foreign key is not nullable, and if I don't include the property Ad_Id in the Picture, the system don't removes the picture, it only sets the Id not NULL, why?